# Big Blue Button installation error: "Challenge failed for domain", thereafter "500 Internal Server Error -- nginx"

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, webserver, internet, web

**Context:**

- I wanted to install Big Blue Button on a Ubuntu virtual machine via SSH;
- I followed correctly the official tutorial up to [the "Install" section](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/administration/install/#install);
- I entered the following command on the terminal: `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bigbluebutton/bbb-install/v2.7.x-release/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -w -v focal-270 -s <here the domain name> -e <here the email> -g -k` using real data on "here the domain name" and "here the email";
- I got **the instalation error** detailed below;
- Accessing the real "here the domain name" by HTTP gives me "500 Internal Server Error -- nginx";
- It is not accessible by HTTPS: "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

**The installation error** in its full glory:

```
A instalar certbot (0.40.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/certbot.timer → /lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer.
A processar 'triggers' para man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for <here the domain name>
Using the webroot path /var/www/bigbluebutton-default/assets for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain <here the domain name>
http-01 challenge for <here the domain name>
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: <here the domain name>
   Type:   caa
   Detail: CAA record for <HERE THE MAIN DOMAIN NAME> prevents issuance
 - Your account credentials have been saved in your Certbot
   configuration directory at /etc/letsencrypt. You should make a
   secure backup of this folder now. This configuration directory will
   also contain certificates and private keys obtained by Certbot so
   making regular backups of this folder is ideal.
bbb-install: Let's Encrypt SSL request for <here the domain name> did not succeed - exiting
```

**The Let's Encrypt log** in its full glory:

- https://sprunge.us/pQGlat

**Questions:**

1. since the problem appears to have started with the SSL certificate during installation, disabling/removing it could solve the "500 Internal Server Error"?
2. if yes, how to do it without uninstalling and reinstalling Big Blue Button? (I suppose uninstalling and reinstalling would be more traumatic due to leaving residues behind to create brand new errors)
3. if no, how to troubleshoot the "500 Internal Server Error", finding its cause and solution?

Comment: See https://letsencrypt.org/docs/caa/ (also, the full log is leaking the details you have censored in your question).

Comment: I've checked the CAA DNS record for your domain, only globalsign.com is allowed to issue certificates. You might want to contact "pablo" (also named there).

Comment: @Panki I know the full log is leaking the details I've censored. It's just that I don't want the details to be indexed and archived by being on Stack Exchange, but it isn't harmful elsewhere.

Comment: @Panki I already reached the conclusion that I won't be able to issue a certificate, and I don't care about having a certificate. I just want Big Blue Button up and running on HTTP.

Comment: I do not think that is a good idea. BBB is a conference software and to my knowledge does not include any other encryption. You are exposing your users to possible eavesdroppers. This includes credentials aswell as conference contents.

Comment: @Panki Indeed not the brightest idea. But it is just a test environment, not the production one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of losing the connection to the server was pretty simple:

1. [The official tutorial](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/administration/install/) tells to enable a Firewall (ufw) allowing only HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) traffic;
2. If I'm using SSH, I should have enabled port 22 too. Changing this allowed me to connect once again.

Now, about the "500 Internal Server Error" I'm getting through HTTP, [the official troubleshooting page](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/support/troubleshooting#500-internal-server-error) tells GreenLight is at fault, so reinstalling Big Blue Button without GreenLight "solves" it.